# What's good practice of creating variables inside functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to know what's the best way to create variables in functional component. I know useState but what about one time assignment? Like below link, dom are created, so it is ok or should we use something else? Also if I need to store some hard coded value to be used in component how to store that?

```
import React from "react";

const Helper = () => {

  function getLinks() {
    let isSubsribe = getSubscription();
    return isSubsribe
      ? {
          url: `https://xyz`,
          desc: "Go to XYZ",
        }
      : {
          url: `https://abc`,
          desc: "Go to abc",
        };
  }

  let links = getLinks(); 
  let dom = null;
  if(links.url === 'https://xyz')
  dom = <div>Hi XYZ</div>
  else
  dom = <div>Hi ABC</div>

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {dom}
    </React.Fragment>
}
```

Comment: inside functional components, u can use `let` and `const` keywords to create local variables

Comment: Just use normal javascript variable, react is just a superset to help for state rendering.